# Set display none after transition has finished with pure JS

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

How would I set display to none (and vice versa) only after the CSS transition has finished?

This is my current code but it doesn't work nicely – the transition isn't visible because I'm adding/removing `display:none;` straightaway.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var mobile_menu       = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
var mobile_menu_open  = document.querySelector('#open-mobile-menu');
var mobile_menu_close = document.querySelector('#close-mobile-menu');

mobile_menu_open.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    mobile_menu.classList.remove('duration-100', 'ease-in', 'opacity-0', 'scale-95');
    mobile_menu.classList.add('duration-200', 'ease-out', 'opacity-100', 'scale-100');
    mobile_menu.removeAttribute('style'); 

});

mobile_menu_close.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    mobile_menu.classList.remove('duration-200', 'ease-out', 'opacity-100', 'scale-100');
    mobile_menu.classList.add('duration-100', 'ease-in', 'opacity-0', 'scale-95');
    mobile_menu.style.display = "none";

});

</script>
```

I can only think of `setTimeout();` but in most cases it's not considered a proper solution but rather a dirty hack. Do I have any other options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `transitionend` event listener.

```js
mobileMenu.addEventListener('transitionend', setDisplayNone);
```

After the animation is finished, it will execute `setDisplayNone()`. If you only want to run this once, you can add this at the end of the `setDisplayNone` function:

```js
mobileMenu.removeEventListener('transitionend', setDisplayNone);
```

Example:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div')

function setDisplayNone() {
  div.style.display = 'none'
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  div.addEventListener('transitionend', setDisplayNone);
  div.classList.add('transition')
}
```

```css
.transition {
  transition-duration: 3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
<br>
<div id='someDiv'>
  Click the button!
</div>
This text will shift upwards once the div has display:none
```

Comment: Isnt it transitionend for a transtition?

Comment: @Raqha The OP was asking for an animation, I think.

Comment: @Raqha I reread the question, and it *is* a transition. Thank you for pointing that out. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 Thanks for this solution! That's worked a charm for me!